# LiPo discharge circuit doesn't work

Tags: zener, lipo, discharge

A friend of mine gave me this circuit to discharge a 3V7, 5000mAh single-cell LiPoly accu:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOgJTM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The zener is to make sure that the circuit stops when the voltage gets below 2V7, so that the accu doesn't get below the critical voltage of 2V4.

However, this doesn't work. The voltage over the zener is approximately 1V, the voltage over the resistor 2V7. Now the resistor gets a little warm, but more important, the circuit won't stop at 2V7 but at 1V. Am I right?

How can I change the circuit to make it work?

Comment: I think that you should also consider the leakage current of the zener, which will slowly deplete the battery if you leave it connected.

Comment: @clabacchio I will check the voltage every now and then and disconnect it as soon as the voltage gets near 2V7. Is there a problem then? What will the leakage current be?

Comment: @CamilStaps Depends on the part, but looks like about 100uA is a typical ballpark value for a 2.7V Zener, so probably not of much concern with that size battery unless connected for weeks / months.

Comment: @PeterJ okay, then it isn't a problem in this case, _but a very good note for other users_. Thanks both!

Comment: @Hey YO is correct - the battery polarity **OR** the zener need to be reversed (NOT both). It is very very very bad to discharge LiPo to around 1V. This can reduce their lifetimes or kill them beyond recovery and MAY cause flaming destruction if recharge is attempted once they have discharged too low.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to connect the zener reversed. Cathode of the zener must connect to the positive terminal of the battery.

Zener voltage of the zener diode is only effective in the reverse direction. In this connection it works like a regular diode.